# Does changing your Twitter password force re-auth on Firebase?

Tags: firebase-authentication

If I'm using Firebase Auth with Sign in with Twitter, does changing my Twitter password kick current logged in people out and force them to re-authenticate?

Comment: Awesome, I checked it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase won't (it can't even) detect that the Twitter password has changed, to this operation has no effect on the user's status on Firebase authentication.